# google chrome ajax call doesn't show arabic characters in js concole

Tags: php, google-chrome, arabic

i am using ajax for data in arabic characters and everything works good , i can store arabic characters to database and i can retrieve arabic characters from database and prints it to the screem and everything works good , but my problem is that when i check **javascripte concole on google chrome** to check the retriveing data i can't show arabic characters , but the prints as this **(this is just example and not all data)**

```
["\u0645\u062f\u064a\u0646\u0629","\u0645\u062f\u064a\u0646\u0629 \u062a\u0627\u0631\u064a\u062e\u064a\u0651\u0629","\u0634\u062e\u0635\u064a\u0651\]
```

i mean like this

[image]

Comment: Last closing (double) quotes is missing. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @inhan don't worry i just give you as example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using JSON, strings are in UTF-8, and special characters are encoded as `\u` followed by 4 hexadecimal characters.

In your case, if you try to decode that string -- for example, with the first item of your array :

```
>>> str = "\u0645\u062f\u064a\u0646\u0629";
"مدينة"
```

I don't read arabic, but this looks like arabic to me :-)

Even if the JSON doesn't *look good*, it's not what matters : the important thing is that you get your original data back, once the JSON is decoded ; and, here, it seems you'll do.

To get the original, decoded, string in the browser's console *(for debugging purposes, I suppose)*, you should be able to use the same JS library you are using in your application *(if any)*, or the `JSON.parse()` function *(I just tested this in Firefox's console, actually)* :

```
>>> JSON.parse('"\u0645\u062f\u064a\u0646\u0629"');
"مدينة"
```

Of course, you'll have to write some code to actually output that decoded-value to the browser's console *(be it "by hand" or when getting the JSON back from your server)* ; but since the browser's console it a debugging tool it seems OK.

By default, the console, as a debugging tool, outputs the raw JSON string it gets from the server -- and, with JSON, special characters are encoded, there is nothing you can do about it *(except decode the JSON string and display it yourself, if you need to)*

If you want to output the decoded string to the console each time you get a result from your server, you'll have to call `JSON.parse()` each time you get a result from your server ; and then output it, probably using `console.log()`.

Don't forget to remove that debugging code before distributing your application / uploading it to your production server, though.

Comment: yes it is arabic , and i know what u said , but my question was how to display that arabic characters in js concloe ?

Comment: i can read the decode string good , but i want to display it as arabic characters to js concole

Comment: by decoding the JSON-string, like you would in your application *(I suppose you are using some javascript library that can do that for you ; JSON.Parse can also be helpful -- I'l edit my answer with an example)*

Comment: man , i can read that charecters well on my html php code , BUT I WANT TO DISPLAY IT ON JS CONCOLE

Comment: you can call that JS function from the console, of course :-) *(that's precisely what I did, with the code I added when editing my answer, actually)*

Comment: @PascalMARTIN read the question again , he doesn't want to decode it on his code , because that works good with him , but he wants to display that on Js Concole

Comment: `$results = $this->model->getIOsForConcept($conceptName);
            $i = 0;
            $IOs = array();
            while ($row = $results->fetch()) {
                $IOs[$i] = $row['name'];
                $i++;
            }
            return json_encode($IOs);`
this is the code , please where should i use JSON .parse ?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan the console is a debugging tool ; the browser displays the raw JSON string it gets from the server in it ; here, the JSON is correct ; if, for debugging purposes, you want to display the decoded JSON, you'll have to write some code to decode it and display it *(even if that is to the console)*

Comment: @PascalMARTIN how can i add the JSON.parse() to the google chrome js conclole ?

Comment: @PascalMARTIN that is greate , now i understand u , u mean i have to use concole.log to prints arabic characters to js concole , and it works with me , but when i used AJAX i just see the link and when clicked that link in js concole i see the response and my question now how can i applya JSON.parse() to that response ?

Comment: When you click on your link, you see the JSON string as it is returned by the server -- and that's it, there isn't much you can do about it *(I don't have chrome to check, but I'm pretty sure)*.

Comment: it is ok man i will keep searching for that , and really thank you for helping , i accept your answer

Comment: @PascalMARTIN please the last thing , in the server this is the returned data echo json_encode(array($concepts, $relations)); , what should it be after using JSON.parse please ?

Comment: The server-side script lloks OK to me, as it apparently returns valid JSON. On the client-side, well, I would use console.log on the value you get after using JSON.parse, first -- and, maybe, after, use some kind of loop to display the different elements of your array.

Comment: @PascalMARTIN yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyes man , it wooooooooorks , thaaaaaaaaaaaaaank you , i love you really